# Segmentation fault (Core dumped) in C while using fscanf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm working in C and gettting segmentation fault (core dumped). The code compiles fine.
inputfile is the output of the top command, and I only want to return the rows by the root user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(){
FILE* file = fopen("C:/Users/danie/OneDrive/Desktop/inputfile.txt", "r");
if (file == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file");
}
char* user[10];
char* ptr[10];
char* ptr1[10];
char* ptr2[10];
char* ptr3[10];
char* ptr4[10];
char* ptr5[10];
char* ptr6[10];
char* ptr7[10];
char* ptr8[10];
char* ptr9[10];
char* ptr10[10];
while (fscanf(file, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s", ptr, user, ptr1, ptr2,ptr3, ptr4, ptr5, ptr6, ptr7, ptr8, ptr9,ptr10)==1){
        if (strcmp(user,"root")==1)
printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", ptr, user, ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, ptr4, ptr5, ptr6, ptr7, ptr8, ptr9, ptr10);

}
}
```

Edit: Thank you all for your help! I'm super new to C. Clearly I had a lot of misunderstandings. I no longer receive the segmentation fault, but my output file is a bunch of nonsense. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gNki.jpg

Comment: Do you know what the return value of fscanf() means? Plus: `char* user[10];` is an array of ten *pointers* PLUS `main()` should return int.

Comment: Get rid of all the stars (`*`) in each `char*`. And while at it, change each `%s` to `%9s`.

Comment: `char* user[10];` and all other declarations aren't pointer of 10 bytes char vectors, they're vectors of 10 uninitialized pointers to char (vectors). If you need pointers to a vector of 10 element you have to use `char user[10]`, in this way `user` is a pointer to a 10 bytes vector.

Comment: Thank you. I made those changes, though I am still receiving the error.

Comment: If your fopen fails, you continue anyway.  You should exit (return) if it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A segmentation fault is a memory access error.
Replace all the `char* name_of_array[10];` into `char name_of_array[10];` as arrays are pointers themselves. This `char* name_of_array[10];` is an array of pointers.

Then I see another error: according to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/), `fscanf` returns the number of items successfully filled. So instead of `if(fscanf(file, ...) == 1)` write `if(fscanf(file, ...) != 0)` (or better `if(fscanf(file, ...))`).

A similar error appears in `if(strcmp(user, "root") == 1)`: it should be `if(strcmp(user, "root") == 0)` ([documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)).

I hope this helps you.

---

**EDIT:** I managed to make it work, although it probably can be improved.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char pid[10];
    char user[10];
    char pr[10];
    char ni[10];
    char virt[10];
    char res[10];
    char shr[10];
    char s[10];
    char cpu[10];
    char mem[10];
    char time[10];
    char command[10];

    FILE* file = fopen("C:/Users/danie/OneDrive/Desktop/inputfile.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file");
    }

    char line[150];
    while (fgets(line, 150, file) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(line, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s", pid, user, pr, ni, virt, res, shr, s, cpu, mem, time, command);

        if(strcmp(user, "root") == 0)
        {
            printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s", pid, user, pr, ni, virt, res, shr, s, cpu, mem, time, command);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made those changes, but am still receiving the error. https://imgur.com/a/TyGnv4g here is the input file

Comment: How about `if(fscanf(file, ...) == 12)`?

Comment: Do you really need to do it in c? Couldn't you use another language like Python or at least C++? Unless you have specific needs, c isn't the right programming language to parse files in an easy way (especially in your case where the spaces between words and the lengths of the words themselves are not fixed), but if you need to use c I'll try to code a parser.

Comment: Yes, it has to be c. I have the code working now, but the output file is nonsense. Please see the edit I made

Comment: Sorry, it got more complicated than I thought. Can you tell me which operating system you will run the application on? Linux or Windows?

Comment: I am using windows

Answer (score 1):

The *ptrs[10] need to be just ptr[10] else you are allocating an array of pointers rather than an array of characters.

Not sure about the Windows top program but the linux one puts out a blank line at times. I consider it a bad idea to have scanf() a file in a while() loop.

```
char buffer[256];
while (fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), file ) ) { 
        if ( ! strstr( buffer, " root " ) ) 
                continue;
```

Now you can inspect input before processing it. This root test is in addition to the one looking at "user" to filter out any odd lines from **top** we know are not to be printed, including strangely formatted lines.

Same idea to avoid using sscanf() return values within an **if** as I like to pop the field return count into a variable:

```
int slen = sscanf(buffer, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s",
                ptr, user, ptr1, ptr2,ptr3, ptr4, ptr5, ptr6, ptr7, ptr8, ptr9,ptr10);
if ( slen >= 10 )
```

This defends against short lines without a **user**, say a blank line.

If you never print anything it may be because your **top** program is putting out a bunch of terminal control codes for colors, etc., before each line potentially messing up your fields.  I had to had edit out of my data file to get the code to work.